# Need help with my first perl program

Tags: perl

I am only a few days in and have only made a couple things from the book I have been going through, so go easy :P. I have tried searching online and have tried different ways but I can not seem to pass the MAC properly to system().
What I am trying to achieve is have perl open a .txt file of MAC's each MAC is on its own separate line. Then with it reading each line taking one MAC at a time and passing it system() as an arg so aircrack can be passed the MAC arg. I have it showing the MAC being read each line properly but I can not figure out why aircrack complains the MAC its being given is not a valid MAC. Is this due to me not chomping the line read?

What I have not tried as of yet due to this complication is I eventually want it to print a found key to a file if aircrack says it has found one, or if it does not find one moves on to the next BSSID, continuing until there are no more MACs in the file to try.

the MACs are in a txt file as so

```
00:00:00:00:00:00
00:00:00:00:00:00
00:00:00:00:00:00
```

and so on

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;


my $file = '/kismetLOGS/PcapDumpKismet/WEPMACS.txt';
open my $info, $file or die "Could not open $file: $!";

while( my $line = <$info>) 
  {
    print $line;
    system("/usr/local/bin/aircrack-ng", "-b $line", "*.pcap *.pcapdump");
    last if $. == 0;
  }

close $info;
exit;
```

Thanks for any help, tips and pointers. Not looking for a spoon feed :) And hopefully I posted properly for everyone and if I am way off in how I am trying this for my end goal please feel free to say and any tips about the correct route to try would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either combine all your arguments together, like

```
system("/usr/local/bin/aircrack-ng -b $line *.pcap *.pcapdump");
```

or separate them all, like

```
system("/usr/local/bin/aircrack-ng", "-b","$line", "*.pcap","*.pcapdump");
```

The latter is usually safer, for spaces in the items not to need be escaped. But then globbing doesnt work, as the arguments are passed directly to the system for execution.

If you want *.pcap to work, you'll need to go with the first version.

Comment: Thank you for that so quickly, that appears to pass the MAC properly but now for some reason it is not opening the pcap's, saying no file or directory. I thought calling system() was like using command line in the location the perl script is run from? The .pcaps are in the same location and it can not find them. How do I make it pass that properly?

Comment: you might need to add an absolute path name to it.

Comment: It's not the directory of the Perl file, it's in whatever directory you were in when you ran the script. (Maybe they were the same.)

Comment: This is an old question/answer, but I think the answer was also in his question - I think he also needs to chomp the input, otherwise won't the system call will ignore the pcap stuff

Answer (score 1):

$line ends with a newline character. You should remove the newline character.

```
chomp $line;
```

Answer (score 0):

about `last if $. == 0;`,change it to `last if $. ~~ 0` which infers the type of the variables when doing the comparison. Remove it if you want to iterate over all of the MAC addresses, as is it will only run on the first ( 0th ) line.